# LWC losing input values when used on another record page

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a pretty simple component on the Case record page with 4 radio input fields wrapped in a record-view-form that are set using case fields when the component is loaded.

In the console, if I move to a different case tab and change the values in the component on that case then return to the previous case, the component loses the input values on the previous case (completely blank radio buttons).

Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Found this which helped me get to the solution. [Radio option getting unchecked automatically when new record is opened in a tab](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/258125/radio-option-getting-unchecked-automatically-when-new-record-is-opened-in-a-tab)

Turns out HTML uses the "name" of a radio group to determine if multiple inputs belong to the same group. So each radio input needs to have a unique name to be used across tabs. I ended up concatenating the record Id to the radio group names and that solved it.